# What does the Android Studio delegateBuildRunToGradle do?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to resolve some dependency issues when using an externally installed Gradle, rather than the one that come with Android Studio (AS). I then came across the particular AS setting under
`File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle > Runner`.

**`[x] Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle`**

[image]

This is apparently also available as the Gradle config `delegateBuildRunToGradle`. But I can't find any sane explanation as to what it does. I thought all AS builds used Gradle...

While the Gradle [doc page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#delegate_build_gradle) say it's on by default. This was not the case for my AS 3.2.2.

[image]

**What does this option do?**
(When should it be used?)

Comment: Somebody posted an answer here, that I was about to accept, but now its gone. Very weird stuff going on here.

Comment: It was Self-deleted. OPs last comment (which you likely didn't get notified about) said: "Hmmm... you're right. I don't know if the functionality has changed, or if my original understanding was incorrect. I'll delete the answer and perhaps return if I reach a higher level of enlightenment"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping to have a more precise answer, but since nothing has come forward here, I guess the only answer is that (what is written in the screenshot above) the *IntelliJ IDEA* has it's own way to make the builds. For many practical purposes it is probably better to have a more updated and working Gradle installation and **enable** the above option, to let it do its job.